# Android problems loading .so file

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, linker-errors

I am working on an android POS device running on version 4.2.2 i need to make use of the serialPort api to communicate with the printer i have configured the gradle to create the libs folder zipped with the generated .apk file

```
02-25 10:18:59.956 29180-29180/com.amedora.slrtcpos E/linker: load_library(linker.cpp:771): too small to be an ELF executable: /data/app-lib/com.amedora.slrtcpos-1/libserial_port.so
02-25 10:18:59.956 29180-29180/com.amedora.slrtcpos E/dalvikvm: dlopen("/data/app-lib/com.amedora.slrtcpos-1/libserial_port.so") failed: Cannot load library: load_library(linker.cpp:771): too small to be an ELF executable: /data/app-lib/com.amedora.slrtcpos-1/libserial_port.so
02-25 10:18:59.970 29180-29180/com.amedora.slrtcpos E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: load_library(linker.cpp:771): too small to be an ELF executable: /data/app-lib/com.amedora.slrtcpos-1/libserial_port.so
```

[image: This is the structure of JNI folder]

I need help can someone tell me why it is saying too small to be an ELF executable

Comment: I found the solution... i .so file is empty when i unzipped the apk and check  the size of it file i discovered it is 0 kb. i discovered its is issue with my jni file configuration issue i configured and did ndk-build through command prompt and it is working fine

Answer (score 2):

```
too small to be an ELF executable: /data/app-lib/com.amedora.slrtcpos-1/libserial_port.so
```

means that you have a zero-length file with above path.